# How to get value of textbox created on the client side in the code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am creating dynamic textboxes using jquery. I want to access each textbox value in the code behind using asp.net.

**HTML (.aspx)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
            var div = $("<div />");
            div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
            $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
        });

    function GetDynamicTextBox() {
        return '<input id="dynamictxtbx" name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" />&nbsp;'
    }
</script>
```

**Codebehind (.aspx.cs)**

```
protected void ListView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // I want to access values here //
}
```

I want to access the values inside the `ListView1_ItemUpdating` function. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857834/asp-net-adding-controls-client-side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all You need to provide unique **id** to the dynamic control You're adding because html won't allow you to add any element with duplicate id. Also You can get the text value, ensure that you have set the name property of textbox like given below while dynamically adding it.

```
'<input id="dynamictxtbxuniqueID" name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" />'
```

Now in order to get it into the code behind use the below mentioned **C# code** to access the dynamic textbox

```
//Get the Textbox value
string textboxval = Request.Form["DynamicTextBox"];
```

Use this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/2052356.aspx?How%20to%20get%20values%20from%20dynamically%20jquery%20created%20textbox%20and%20dropdownlist%20in%20code%20behind%20) for further reference

Comment: :Request.Form cannot work here,because iam using a listview and in code behind using ListView1_ItemUpdating.

Comment: @hakkeem: Yes it can work. You won't be able to access the values in any other way, since your controls were not created on the server side.

Comment: @Mukesh Kumar:How can i get each dynamic textbox value seperately?

Comment: @Jenny O'Reilly:How can i get each dynamic textbox value seperately?

Comment: You have to give every textbox a unique name attribute and use that name for the Request.Form collection.