# Get input textbox values in the codebehind from the client

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, database, code-behind

I have created a JavaScript button that will add 4 textboxes and a fileupload control on the clients browser.  They can add as many of these as they need too.

My issue now is on the submit button how can I loop through these controls to get the values to put in my database?

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rownum = 1;

function AddRow() {

  var div = document.createElement("div")

  var divid = "dv" + rownum
  div.setAttribute("ID", divid)
  rownum++

  var txtFName = document.createElement("input")
  txtFName.setAttribute("ID", "txtFName" + rownum)
  txtFName.placeholder = "First Name";
  txtFName.style.width = "190px";
  rownum++
  var txtLName = document.createElement("input")
  txtLName.setAttribute("ID", "txtLName" + rownum)
  txtLName.placeholder = "Last Name";
  txtLName.style.width = "190px";
  rownum++
  var txtEmail = document.createElement("input")
  txtEmail.setAttribute("ID", "txtEmail" + rownum)
  txtEmail.placeholder = "Email";
  txtEmail.style.width = "289px";
  rownum++
  var txtInst = document.createElement("input")
  txtInst.setAttribute("ID", "txtAge" + rownum)
  txtInst.placeholder = "Age";
  txtInst.style.width = "100px";
  rownum++
  var _upload = document.createElement("input")
  _upload.setAttribute("type", "file")
  _upload.setAttribute("ID", "upload" + rownum)
  _upload.setAttribute("runat", "server")
  _upload.setAttribute("name", "uploads" + rownum)      
  _upload.style.width = "610px";
  rownum++

  var btnRemove = document.createElement("input")
  btnRemove.type = "button";      
  btnRemove.setAttribute("onclick", "return RemoveDv('" + divid + "');");
  btnRemove.innerText = "Remove";
  rownum++

  var _pdiv = document.getElementById("ParentDiv")

  div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))      
  div.appendChild(txtFName)      
  div.appendChild(txtLName)      
  div.appendChild(txtEmail)
  div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
  div.appendChild(txtInst)
  div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
  div.appendChild(_upload)
  div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
  div.appendChild(btnRemove)
  div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))      
  _pdiv.appendChild(div)
}

function RemoveDv(obj) {
  var p = document.getElementById("ParentDiv")
  var chld = document.getElementById(obj)
  p.removeChild(chld)
}
```

ASP.aspx

```
<table width="100%" class="pagetext_10">
<tr>
    <td colspan="10">
      <input type="button" onclick="AddRow(); 
           return false;" value="Add Employees" />&nbsp;
      <div id="ParentDiv" style="width:100%;">
      </div><br /><br />          
    </td>
   </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: Take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857834/asp-net-adding-controls-client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through all values in the `Request` object, try:

```
foreach (string s in Request.Form.Keys )        
{       
   var formValue = Request.Form[s];      
}
```

As long as you know your field prefixes you should be able to identify your dynamic ones.

---

If you have a fixed 12 field controls, 3 upload controls, instead of creating the form fields with JavaScript, you could show / hide server controls for your hidden fields, then the values will be available as normal during the page lifecycle.

If the unused ones are wrapped in an element with `display: none;` then they will not be set to the server.

---

As you only have 4 dynamic fields, you can read them out of the request directly:

```
var result1 = Request.Form("txtFName1");
// etc ..
```

If you can submit without these fields, check for null:

```
if (Request.Form["txtFName1"] != null)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

If the number of buttons is dynamic as long as you can submit the number back too you should be able to loop through.

Then you would need to add a button to submit the form:

aspx:

```
<asp:Button id="Submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
```

code behind:

```
public void Submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Nikolai,  Thank you for your reply.  I have 5 fields per button click.  If the user have 3 employees to add there will be a total of 12 input textboxes and 3 input file upload controls.    Is there a way to look through the controls to get the values on the server, even though the controls on client side?

Comment: If its a fixed amount instead of creating with them with javascript, you can show / hide already existing form fields that are server controls.

Comment: You would also be able to do a `foreach` over each `key` within the `Request`.

Comment: It's not a set amount of employees added.  So it can be 0 one time or 5 the next.  It all depends on who is entering it and how many employees they are dealing with so the number of controls is never set in stone.    From the codebehind in C# can I access the client side div and loop through the input controls?

Comment: You can only loop through a div server side, if it was created serverside with `runat=server`. You can loop through the request object, which should give you almost the same.

Comment: How can I loop through all request objects?  In your example you have Request.Form["control name"], but what if I don't know the control names what code would I use to loop through the collection?  Thank you so much

Comment: See latest edit, you can use `Request.Form.Keys` to get all the keys that are part of the form submission.

Comment: I checked Request.Form.Keys and I don't see the dynamically created controls that are on the client side.  I see all the server side textbox controls.  Do I have to set something for me to see them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104211/discussion-between-jerry-warra-and-nikolaidante).

Comment: No, that'll contain anything submitted. Are you creating them within a `<form>` tag?

Comment: They are within a content page of a master page.  The master page does have a form tag.  The div and the controls are on the client side not server side.

Comment: Hi Nikolai,  I figured it out.  I was only using ID property and not name.  I added the name value for my controls and now I can see them in the serverside code.  Do I revise my question with my fix or should I post a new comment?  Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your responses, I was watching TV... :-) Glad you got it sorted! Personally I think the name bit was a separate question to the "how do I read dynamic form values in the code behind?" one but its your question ;-)